# Android webview javascript function not working for anchor tag

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Anchor tag click event is not working in android jellybean 4.2.2 using webview, In above version it is working fine.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('Accounts').click();})()");
```

This is my anchor tag and I cannot change this.

```
<a href="Finacle;jsessionid=0000AT9YD5vrnOS9NJzIjdjJ4PD:1a33q40b7?bwayparam=j%2B2uf%2FBHaNA0ZGWt4ROCCTymgTzXQqv11%2Bfo1g9Jr8Zb1X2StMH26Jd%2FQ0EiE794ALKyEOjpbxhCm3IPgN61zCmWB5ZhKo2OiZRnAsRFLde2n56Kv4yz8ENMvTFzO6T8%0D%0AtXQFDgFsZMbGS28KN44DLVBb%2FQGDyNdvWhqaDSd5aqZEjDO0l1B%2F6x6RovcROwnJSFAG3awM%2FmbNHLvuSTcrwYeETC8B7UVmQBproSd7%2BC0%3D" 
id="Accounts" name="HREF_Accounts">Accounts</a>
```

**Got solution:**
IF click() is not implemented using android js interface, we have to use HTML DOM Event Object, like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+
    "l=document.getElementById('Accounts');"+
    "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');"+
    "e.initEvent('click',true,true);"+
    "l.dispatchEvent(e);"+
    "})()");
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22866913/5370550

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is EventBinding. When you call the function in webView.loadUrl, it does not find element with that id in the dom and unable to bind. To prevent this problem you have to use `.on()` function. Eg

```
$('#Accounts').on('click',function(){
//...
});
```

Now with this method, any element with this id will be bind with this event.

Comment: How can I convert this using javascript?

Comment: You can directly add this jquery as javascript. Like WebView.loadUrl("javascript:$('#Accounts').on('click',function(){
//...
});")

Comment: Also don't forget to enable javascript on the webview :

WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: this is not working It showing in console VM6987:1 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: did you add myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); ??

Comment: add this right after "webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);" this function in next line.
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

Comment: import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

Comment: added same
webView.setWebViewClient(new MeWebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150462/discussion-between-nik-and-dalvinder-singh).