# Click on button submit from Android webView doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview

I have a login form (made with WordPress) and I want the user of the application to access the web directly without having to login again.

With code, I am able to fill in the form fields (username and password), but I cannot click on the button.

My code is this:

```
WebSettings webSettings= wvProductos.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    wvProductos.loadUrl("MYWEB/SHOP/");
    wvProductos.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    wvProductos.loadUrl(
"javascript:document.getElementById('username').value = '29075431G';" +
"javascript:document.getElementById('password').value = '29075431';" +
"javascript:document.getElementsByName('login').click();" );

}
});
```

I can fill the fields Username and Password, but the click event don't work.

any suggestions?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709963/programmatic-click-in-android-webview

Comment: Yes, I tried that solution, but nothing happens :(

Comment: Oops! I solved! My issue was in the tag 'getElementsByName' that it is plural and will return an array so then its necesary declare the first return value getElementsByName('login')[0].click()

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to set `webViewClient` (and maybe `webChromeClient`).